# Make a query dynamically depending on ComboBox choice

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making a query involving 2 tables in C#. The query works fine when I input information into all the combo boxes. But when I try to make query with some empty combo boxes, it returns nothing.

I get that it is cos the string ends up having "" in the query which makes it invalid. Is there anyway I could restructure my query to make it possible to make queries with missing entries or even a missing secondary table? Thanks for advice.

The following works when I fill up all fields and make the query:

[image]

If I fill up only paritial fields as follows, it won't work:

[image]

My query String:

```
string query = @"SELECT Agents." + comboq1.Text + ",  Agents." + comboq2.Text + ", Agents." + comboq3.Text + ", Agents." + comboq4.Text + ", "
                                + secondaryTable.Text + "." + stCombo1.Text + ", " + secondaryTable.Text + "." + stCombo2.Text
                                + " FROM Agents INNER JOIN " + secondaryTable.Text + " ON Agents.Dept_ID" + "="
                                + secondaryTable.Text + ".Dept_ID";
```

Comment: How do you query the database, what type of query do you get? (as a test you can write it to the console). Furthermore although you are using comboboxes, you should be careful for SQL injection.

Comment: I am displaying the query on a dataGrid and it returns the relevant table data correctly as long as I fill up all combo boxes. A little off topic maybe but why do I need to worry about SQL injection here? They only get to choose from options I give. Nothing for user to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string agentsValue = string.empty;
if (!comboq1.Text.equals(string.empty))
{ agentsValue = "Agents."+comboq1.text; }
if (!agentsValue.equals(string.empty))
{ agentsValue +=","; }
if (!comboq2.Text.equals(string.empty))
{ 
if (agentsValue.equals(string.empty))
{ agentsValue = "Agents."+comboq2.text; }
else
{ agentsValue += "Agents."+comboq2.text; }
}
```

please follow the above code for rest of the combo boxes and while adding the value of the second combo box add a comma in between the values. After building the string in this format you can then append it to your query and now when you execute the query you should not find any kind of errors.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a separate string by checking that if any combo box does not provide any value then omit that combo box value from the string and then append the final string to you query which will not cause any problem.